# Modifying a datetime field in Laravel migration

Tags: laravel, eloquent, migration

I need to make a migration to add default value to a datetime field that already exists. This isnt working:

```
$table->timestamp('birth_date')->useCurrent()->change();
```

When I try to run the migration it returns

```
 SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'birth_date'
```

The change() method isnt taking effect

Also I cant figure out how to make the rollback

Comment: Your updating `birth_date`, but in the error it says `created_at`. Are you adding the timestamps again?

Comment: Copied it from another place but its returning the same error

Comment: Are you sure you are calling the table method, and not the create metod of the Schema facade?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `useCurrent()` method, [`useCurrent`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Grammars/MySqlGrammar.php#L564) is a column value, so try something like this:

```
$table->timestamp('birth_date')->useCurrent = true;
```

Also, raw query will definitely work:

```
$table->timestamp('birth_date')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP');
```

Comment: Alan updating `birth_date`, but in the error it says `created_at` as duplicate column. Did you notice it?

Comment: Copied it from another place but its returning the same error

Comment: @Alan please post both migrations.